# How CloudKit throw the incompatibleVersion error?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

there is a error code named 'incompatibleVersion'.

The docs says:

> The CloudKit servers have determined that your app is out of date. Alert your user to upgrade to the newest version of your app. This error is nonrecoverable.

I wonder how CloudKit determine the app is out of date? I can't find any settings to tell iCloud Dashboard supported app version.

Comment: Which API method did return this error?

Comment: @Ely I don't know. I was plan to handle CKErrors and saw this error code from the docs.